# Can we use split in ng-options in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Can I do something like this?

```
<select ng-model="account" ng-options="account.split('|')[0] for account in getCustomerName()">
```

Is this a valid `ng-options` code?

Comment: Why not just **try** it and see yourself? Don't be scared, your computer won't explode if it fails.

Answer (score 2):

#### Have you tried that?

Well, of course, yes

```js
var a = angular.module("sa", [])

a.controller("foobar", function($scope) {
  
  $scope.getCustomerName = function() {
    return ['Foo|2', 'Bar|3'];
  };
  
  $scope.account = $scope.getCustomerName()[0];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="sa" ng-controller="foobar">
  <select ng-model="account" ng-options="account.split('|')[0] for account in getCustomerName()"></select>

  <div>selected: {{account}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This gives me desired output but as usual, it also gives a blank value. I have set $scope.account as the first value in the controller, but it still remains blank.

Comment: No it don't seems to be giving me the blank value. See the updated result.